# Populate Contact Form 7 Posted Data with API Response

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I am trying to populate the `$posted_data["dynamichidden-458"];` with the PHP variable `$body`  $body is an API response which I want to add to the data which is then sent to the data layer to later be captured, below is an example code of how it sends and receives the API information. Using `wpcf7_before_send_mail` I send the information to retrieve the response from the API, where I will then later add in a `wpcf7_mail_sent` to post all the required information.

I capture the `$body` variable with a debugger which allows me to debug the response to my log, but it fails to populate the `$posted_data["dynamichidden-458"];`, other variations I have tried include `$posted_data["dynamichidden-458"] = $body;` but it still won't post the `$body` variable under `dynamichidden-458"`.

What else can be done to try to populate the posted data with my PHP variable?

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'Kiri_cf7_api_sender' );
function Kiri_cf7_api_sender( $contact_form ) {

    if ( $contact_form->title === 'Quote_form' ) {
        $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();

        if ( $submission ) {
            $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();

            $name    = $posted_data['your-name'];
            $surname = $posted_data['your-name2'];
            $phone   = $posted_data['tel-922'];
            $urltest = $posted_data['dynamichidden-739'];
            $body    = $posted_data['dynamichidden-458'];

            if ( strpos( $urltest, '?phone' ) !== false ) {
                $url = 'api string';

            } elseif ( strpos( $urltest, '?email' ) !== false ) {
                $url = 'api string';

            } else {
                $url = 'api string';

                $response = wp_remote_post( $url );
                $body     = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response );

                ob_start();                     // start buffer capture

                var_dump( $name );
                var_dump( $surname );
                var_dump( $phone );
                var_dump( $url );
                var_dump( $urltest );
                var_dump( $body );

                $contents = ob_get_contents();  // put the buffer into a variable
                ob_end_clean();                 // end capture
                error_log( $contents );
                return;
                print_r( $submission );

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm confused about how you're getting the $body from the API response to go anywhere.  Also, you have a `print_r` after `return` which neither of these will do anything.  You don't need to return anything from this function, since it's an action and not a filter.  So can you clarify what you expect to happen with this: `$body     = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response );` and how this `$body    = $posted_data['dynamichidden-458'];` has an effect on `$body` since the API response would overwrite this.

Comment: Hi Howard, yes so the print_r and return were brought from the working example code but they do not work as it doesn't print the information for the user to be seen on wordpress. As of now the ```$body    = $posted_data['dynamichidden-458']; ``` overwrites the value of body with it's own value, what I want is for ```$body``` to be the value of ```$posted_data['dynamichidden-458'];```

Comment: What does it do for you if the $body of the API response is equal to a submitted field?  Does it need to pass to the email or something?  To be clear... There is no user output from this hook.  This is all happening in an ajax action (and wp-json api).  So the `print_r( $submission );` will never output anything, unless you dump it to the error_log like the previous error log dump.

Comment: So when a user inputs their details into my form, the form then posts their information via the API, which then gives the form a response whether or not the information sent is valid, if the user information sent is valid that bunch of new user information will be given an ID in the response like so ```<leadID>LRP-5089321</leadID>```. When a contact form fires you can capture the information that is posted by the form which comes out like the comment below

Comment: ```inputs: Array(5)
0: {name: 'your-name', value: 'kiri'}
1: {name: 'your-name2', value: 'test'}
2: {name: 'tel-922', value: '1234567890'}
3: {name: 'dynamichidden-739', value: 'https://myurll.com'}
4: {name: 'dynamichidden-458', value: ''}
length: 5
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)```   this can be captured with google tag manager which will allow me to track which users belong to the ID for separate marketing purposes. ```$body``` is used to get the response, but now I want ```$body``` to be the value in ```$posted_data['dynamichidden-458']; ```.

Comment: So is the variable that's to be replaced supposed to go in the email or is it supposed to output to the screen? If it's just to go in the email then doesn't really need to go to the screen right?

Comment: If you're asking this to the tag manager data layer, what kind of script are you using for that?

Comment: Yes, so it would only need to be in the output part like the email, but the form isn't sending the email anywhere just outputting the information, I don't have a exact script for the tag manager yet as I am wanting to first see if I can bundle everything in the form output, here is a example tag manager where it records all the inputs, outputted from a form ```<script>
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
 window.dataLayer.push({
 "event" : "cf7submission",
 "formId" : event.detail.contactFormId,
 "response" : event.detail.inputs
 })
}); 
</script>```

Answer (score 1):

What it sounds like you want to do is first update the mail body with a string replacement, rather than using some hidden variable. With that, you can do something like this in your contact form mail tab.  Where `{{api_response}}` will be replaced by whatever you define in the function `Kiri_cf7_api_sender`

```
/** Contact Form 7 Mail Tab in Editor **/
Dear [your-name],

This is the email body...

{{api_response}}

"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
```

So now for the function `Kiri_cf7_api_sender`

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'Kiri_cf7_api_sender' );
function Kiri_cf7_api_sender( $contact_form ) {

    if ( 'Quote_form' === $contact_form->title ) {
        $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();

        if ( $submission ) {
            $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();

            $name    = $posted_data['your-name'];
            $surname = $posted_data['your-name2'];
            $phone   = $posted_data['tel-922'];
            $urltest = $posted_data['dynamichidden-739']; // Not sure if this should be a form field, or just some kind of option field.
            
            if ( strpos( $urltest, '?phone' ) !== false ) {
                $url = 'api string';

            } elseif ( strpos( $urltest, '?email' ) !== false ) {
                $url = 'api string';

            } else {
                $url = 'api string';

                $response = wp_remote_post( $url );
                $body     = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response );

            }
        }
        // Get the email tab from the contact form.
        $mail = $contact_form->prop( 'mail' );
        // Retreive the mail body, and string replace our placeholder with the field from the API Response.
        // Whatever the api response is within the $body - if you have to json decode or whatever to get it.
        $mail['body'] = str_replace( '{{api_response}}', $body['field'] , $mail['body'] );
        // Update the email with the replaced text, before sending.
        $contact_form->set_properties( array( 'mail' => $mail ) );
        // Push a response to the event listener wpcf7mailsent.
        $submission->add_result_props( array( 'my_api_response' => $body ) );

    }
}
```

This should at least send the email, and allow you to add the API response to your email.

It also pushes an response to the javascript event `wpcf7mailsent` which can be found by.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener('wpcf7mailsent', function (event) {
        console.log(event.detail.my_api_response);
    }, false);
</script>
```

Comment: So with this, I can't see it being able to then track it with google tag manager to track the events, which is why I was trying to rather get it like this, where I want this ```$posted_data['dynamichidden-458'];``` field to be the same value as ```$body``` because of how I want to track, is there any way of doing this?

Comment: I've updated the answer with a way to push the response back to the page. How you push that to gtag is up to you.  I think that's another question entirely though.  If this works for you, please accept and upvote.  Thanks.